# Web Scraping Using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have created a simple web scraper that pulls in the article titles and URL from this website: http://espn.go.com/college-football/. However, the scraper only returns 46-50 articles, instead of all the articles from the site. I've tried changing the CSS selector that `cheerio` uses, but nothing changes with regards to the number of articles it scrapes. Here is the code I'm using:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", { native_parser: true });


url = 'http://espn.go.com/college-football/';

function Headline(title, link) {
    this.Title = title;
    this.link = link;
}

request(url, function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

        var result = [];

        // Grab the articles titles/url
        $('.text-container h1 a.realStory', '#news-feed-content').each(function (i, elem) {
            console.log($(elem).text(), elem.attribs.href);
            var articleObject = new Headline($(elem).text(), elem.attribs.href);
            result.push(articleObject);
        });
    }

    fs.writeFile('espn_articles.json', JSON.stringify(result, null, 4), function (err) {

        console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');

    })

    db.collection('articles').insert(result, function (error, record) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log("data saved");
    });
});
```

Comment: scroll down page will see content gets added based in `infinite scroll` loading

Comment: @charlietfl Can you elaborate? I know the page auto scrolls, but I'd like to know how to get the articles from scrolling all the way down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using [Osmosis](https://github.com/rchipka/node-osmosis).

```
osmosis('http://espn.go.com/college-football/')
    .find('#news-feed-content .text-container')
    .set({
        author:   '.author',
        category: '.category-link',
        title:    '.realStory',
        link:     '.realStory@href',
        blurb:    'p'
    })
    .follow('.realStory@href')
    .set({
        date:    '.article-meta @data-date',
        images:  [ 'picture @srcset' ],
        content: '.article-body'
    })
    .data(function (article) {
        /*
        { author: '...',
          category: '...',
          title: 'Harbaugh, Michigan reel in Florida OL Herbert',
          link: '...',
          blurb: 'Jim Harbaugh and Michigan have landed another recruit from SEC country in Kai-Leon Herbert of Florida.',
          date: '2016-07-06T17:25:09Z',
          images: [ '...', '...' ],
          content: '...'
        }
        */

        db.collection('articles').insert(article, function (error, record) {
            // ...
        });
    })
    .log(console.log)
    .error(console.log)
    .debug(console.log);
```

Answer (score 2):

when you take a look at the page with the chrome dev tools you'll see that it makes an api call everytime it renders more posts . here's the url : http://cdn.espn.go.com/core/now?render=true&partial=nowfeed&xhr=1&sport=ncf&offset=0&device=desktop&userab=8

I assume that the offset params is used for pagination.

Keep in mind that scraping is "illegal" in certain cases so better to ask for permission first

hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks @Sam. I contacted them and made sure I could scrape the content before starting to project. I guess I'm still lost on how to grab the articles from scrolling down. Should I implement something like PhantomJS?

Comment: Hi, in this case you don't need to. just use a variable instead of the offset value at the url . Good luck